# Selenium with phantom JS has a tendency to hang?

Tags: python, debugging, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Long story short I made this bot to download some stuff from a site and used selenium to connect to the site. I noticed after a couple tries selenium really slows down. So I made a test to check whether I'm just imagining things.

First I stored a list of paths of length 10, like this:

```
paths = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5']
```

Then I created an infinite loop, a counter, and a time detecting system like this:

```
counter = 0

while True:
    counter, path = counter + 1, paths[counter%len(paths)]

    now = datetime.now()

    driver.get(path)

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(('id', 'divImage'))
        ) # search term = (By.CLASS_NAME, 'listing')
    except TimeoutException:
        # Do some stuff on error
        raise

    print(f'({counter}): {(dt.now() - now).total_seconds()}')
```

And then I just let it run in the command prompt. PhantomJS is actually pretty fast most of the time. It takes on average 5 seconds the first time, around the third and fourth time the average drops to 1-2 seconds, but then outta nowhere at about the 15th, 25th or 40th time it just hangs forever with no decrease in time leading up to it. I checked the process and it takes up like 0 cpu, network is sometimes 0mbps or 0.1mpbs.

Now I know this isn't a site problem, there's only 10 items in the list and it connects perfectly fine the first time (in range 0-10). I can only surmise there's something wrong with selenium. Tell me if I'm crazy?

Comment: Did you verify this locally? For a localhost'd website? I use phantomjs to test our locally hosted application which often needs 200 forms created with complex fields, and I don't get this much error margin. Sure sometimes it runs slowly, but that's when the DB is getting challenged. The reason I'm asking if they intentionally slowed your IP down.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin I don't think this is that. I mean if it hangs for over 10 seconds I kill and then restart the program and I'm back to how things are at the start. I would assume if their limiting my IP it should be slow regardless of if I run the program again or not.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin I just updated selenium and apparently support for phantomjs has been discontinued. I'll try and adapt my code to work with headless firefox and get back to u.

Comment: You're right. If the phantomjs distro itself is causing a hang, it's not related to any network issue. Can you post your phantomjs /selenium version? I want to check with mine.

Comment: I updated to the latest version of both, but phantomjs has been discontinued by selenium so kind of a mute point.